# Cheap dual-display HDR UHD graphics card

Tags: graphics-cards

I have two 4k displays that (claim to) support HDR/10-bit color.  One display takes HDMI only, the other takes HDMI or DisplayPort.  I want a graphics card that will drive both of them to 4k HDR under Windows 10.

I don't do any gaming so I don't care about frame-rates.  I mostly want HDR for photo and light video editing, so I'm also guessing that GPU memory doesn't matter.

Computer is a Dell Inspiron 3668 with i7-7700 and 32GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a GTX 1050 for a little over €130, which should be enough. It even supports 8K :). According to rockpapershotgun.com/ the 1050 supports HDR on hdmi and dp. Which 1050 is availible, I don't know, the prices and availibility varies a LOT (just like with other gpus)